# What is the most user-friendly way to show a slug field?

Tags: wording, webforms

In a CMS, objects can have slugs, i.e. parts of URLs to identify the object at the website, for example **my-institution** is a slug in the **http:­//www.example.com/institutions/my-institution/**. Slugs are prefered identifiers for SEO and user experience. However, what is the best understandable way to display a slug in a form for the website users who can create their institutions?

(I am considering the terms "slug" or "permalink" too technical and would like to find some good alternative).

Comment: So you need a synonym and not a way to design the slug field, isn't it?

Comment: Unique Identifier ?

Comment: Either a good synonym or some best-practice GUI element.

Comment: Do the users know about SEO and care about UX? If not, this field is not for them to fill in. No "best understood" term or implementation can fix that.

Comment: According to my understanding, UX should provide the most self explanatory workflows without any deeper knowledge of technical terms whenever possible. SEO is a technical area only important for the functionality of the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course “slug” is too technical, but it’s also too general. A word like “slug” is good for talking about a sort of field. Given instances of the field have their own names.

#### You don’t need to explain “slugs” — just show the user what is happening

Ask for what specifically you want the user to enter: in this case, the **short name of the university**.

- Provide a normal text field for the user to enter the institution
  name.
- Provide instructions that this will be used to create the website
  URL (understanding only some folks will read this).
- Display the resulting URL prominently on the page, labeled “this will by your web address.” This should update as
  the user types, translating spaces to hyphens, etc.
- If the short name exceeds a certain length, pop up a message encouraging the user to keep the name as brief as possible.

Your users will then be able to discover what they’re creating.

Answer (score 3):

If the slug is short, just display it. If the slug is long, truncate it and place a button with the option "Copy" or "See" (text/ icon) after. Slug is ok as term and you can display a note with the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You could use chips to both represent and edit a long slug, provided the full Url is displayed somewhere, Something like this could work:

[image]